# Vuex this.$store is not a function but this.$store.dispatch is executed

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In my App.vue component, I have:

```
mounted () {
   this.$store.dispatch('switchSideNav', false)
   ...
   console.log('COOKIE: ', this.$store.state('cookieAgreement'))
   if (!this.$store.state('cookieAgreement')
     .....
```

this is raising an error:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$store.state is not a function"
```

Checking  Vuex on DevTools, I can see:

```
 state
    cookieAgreement:false
 getters
    getAllState: Object
       cookieAgreement: false
```

why this.store is right with .dispatch(), but not with .state()?

feedback welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 'state' is not a function but 'dispatch' is a function of vuex store. State is an javascript object you can use it with dot notation like other javascript objects. Like this;

```
this.$store.state.cookieAgreement // This returns your value

this.$store.state('cookieAgreement') // This returns error since .state is not a function its an object
```

Comment: thanks a lot , I did not manipulate vuex for weeks... you refreshed my mind !